# Nodejs load and execute file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to to have this return an output ?

**hello.js**

```
var y = 1;

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

**main.js**

```
var x = 42;

var magic = somehowInclude('hello.js');
```

And when you run `main.js` with node it prints `42` and `1`

Is it to possible to do this without `require` and `exports` ?

Comment: some solutions are posted here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file I think you are looking for that jQuery solution mentioned in accepted answer of that question

Comment: @Gatekeeper but this is not client side at all, all this is server side running in node and a web server sadly isnt part of the the setup.

Answer (score 1):

Use Node.js modules.

**hello.js**

```
module.exports.magic = function (x) {
  var y = 1;

  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
};
```

**main.js**

```
var x = 42;

var hello = require('./hello.js');
hello.magic(42);
```

Read the detailed description of the [module loading system](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) at in the Node.js documentation.